# Diamant pour signifier virginité

Tags: expressions

Dans deux chansons au moins ([*les bigotes*](http://www.chansons.ch/paroles/jacques-brel/les-bigotes) et [*vraiment je ne pense qu'à lui*](http://www.parolesmania.com/paroles_jacques_brel_11660/paroles_vraiment_je_ne_pense_qu%C3%A0_lui_1319690.html)), Brel utilise *diamant* pour signifier virginité.  Je ne me souviens pas avoir rencontré cette image ailleurs et tant que je n'avais pas remarqué la deuxième, je pensais qu'il s'agissait d'une de ses inventions (l'ironie dans la première des chansons y aide).  Maintenant que j'ai remarqué la deuxième -- qui n'est pas ironique elle --, je me demande si l'image est plus répandue que je ne le croyais.

Comment: In light of the arguably vague resemblance between the shape of diamonds (when represented 2-dimensionally) & that of “va-jay-jays,” combined with the use of “conserver” in “Les Bigotes” (instead of “preserver” or “sauver,” which, at least in the English equivalents, might be more idiomatic with “virginity” than “conserver”) MAYBE Le Grand Jacques uses diamonds to mean va-j-js & not  virginity. Similarly, in the 2nd song, MAYBE it could mean:“go/come after my v-j-j” (not virginity), although in English the Housekeeper sings of “grimly guard[ing] [her] **honor**,” which does smack of virginity.

Answer (score 1):

L'image est fort répandue à tel point que la bague de fiançailles se doit (se devait ?*) de comporter un diamant, aussi petit soit-il, qui symbolise la virginité de la promise, virginité qu'elle ne perd que le soir de ses noces.

À lire sur Francetvinfo :
[Pourquoi offre-t-on une bague en diamant pour les fiançailles](http://www.francetvinfo.fr/replay-radio/les-pourquoi/pourquoi-offre-t-on-une-bague-en-diamant-pour-les-fiancailles_1789167.html) ?

Et ce titre de femmes actuelles :
[Pas d’hymen, pas de diamant : hommes recherchent femmes à l’hymen intact](http://www.femmeactuelle.fr/actu/news-actu/pas-d-hymen-pas-de-diamant-page-facebook-sexisme-24214).

Mais pourquoi cette symbolique du diamant ? À cause de sa valeur ? De sa transparence et de sa blancheur qui évoque la « pureté » ?

<sup>*Les mœurs évoluent...</sup>

Comment: Dans les deux cas le lien me semble plutôt indirect. Du diamant au mariage et du mariage à la virginité ; le diamant ne semble pas symboliser directement cette dernière comme chez Brel (les bigotes sont pour moi des vieilles filles, et l'autre narratrice craint un viol).  La symbolique qui associe diamant et mariage est pour moi plus portée sur la solidité et la durabilité.

Answer (score 1):

J'adore Brel, mais au moins dans *Les bigottes* l'expression représentent plutôt l'idée que se font de vieilles filles de leur virginité que d'une image communément admise. De mémoire, la chanson dit

> Toutes fières d'avoir pu préserver
> Le diamant qui dort entre leurs f...
>   
> De bigottes

La force de l'image tient ici de l'opposition diamant - fesses de vieilles femmes

Mais je n'ai jamais vu utiliser diamant pour virginité ailleurs que dans Brel. L'image de la virginité est plutôt en France dans la robe blanche.

Answer (score 0):

Je ne connais pas très bien Brel, mais je n'ai jamais entendu ce terme pour parler de la virginité.

C'est fréquent que des chanteurs utilisent des métaphores et expressions qui leurs sont propres, ça serait pas étonnant que ce soit le cas avec Brel.